# Rails + Koala: Recover from exception and continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, koala

Assuming the **message** argument is a string, I have the following snippet:

```
users.each do |user|
 posted = Facebook.post_to_facebook(message,user.token)
end
```

Then, post_to_facebook is a method like this:

```
  def post_to_facebook
   facebook_graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(token)
   object_from_koala = facebook_graph.put_wall_post(message)
  end
```

For some users, when calling the **put_wall_post** I get an exception of this type: `Koala::Facebook::APIError`. I just want to skip posting to that user's wall, and go to the next user, but I fail to see how to do that managing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use rescue like this, and maybe handle your exceptions

```
def post_to_facebook
  begin
    facebook_graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(token)
    object_from_koala = facebook_graph.put_wall_post(message)
  rescue
    do something else
end
```

Comment: By now I don't want to do anything else than skipping to the next user. Would that do the trick?

Comment: when you call `Facebook.post_to_facebook` with the `rescue` block inside, it won't raise an exception, so basically it should go through all the users regardless of any exceptions